# jQuery UI widgets - why is there a changer method available here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been looking at [the example given for a widget factory](http://jqueryui.com/widget/) on the jQuery UI site, and it has this in the code:

```
_create: function() {
   // snip!

   this.changer = $( "<button>", {
     text: "change",
     "class": "custom-colorize-changer"
   })
   .appendTo( this.element )
   .button();
```

I can't find any reference to `.changer` elsewhere. Can you create methods on the fly like this because it's a widget or jQuery or javascript, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.changer` isn't a method, it's a newly created jQuery object that wraps a `<button>` element.

The `this.changer =` syntax is just standard javascript.  The widget object can now reference this button via its `changer` member.

There's nothing particularly special or jQuery-specific about this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought a reference to an object (or an accessor) would have to be declared first and not done on the fly, I can't recall seeing this before. Granted, I don't use javascript a lot so I forget parts.

Comment: @iain in other languages this is true, and even in JavaScript it's a good idea to declare variables with `var` in a particular scope, but since `this` is allocated to memory internally it doesn't make sense to use `var this`.  Members do not need to be initialized.

Comment: That's good to know. I probably need to break out the Javascript book again for a refresher…